# Array prop empty in constructor

Tags: reactjs

I have a component with a prop which is an array of objects.
The problem is that it is empty in `constructor()` even though other props with primitive values are filled also in the `render()` it is also filled.
Why it is like that and how do I get passed array in the constructor?
The component:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Dropdown } from "semantic-ui-react"

class SearchableDropdown extends Component {
    defaultOptions = []
    allOptions = []

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        console.log(props.options) //empty here
    }

    search = (event, { searchQuery }) => {
        console.log(searchQuery)
    }

    render () {
        console.log(this.props.options) //but filled here
        return (
            <Dropdown selection search onSearchChange={this.search} {...this.props}/>
        )
    }
}

export { SearchableDropdown }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Component render:

```js
<SearchableDropdown name='city' value={city} onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder='City' options={this.props.cities}/>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: you need to past some code to get help

Comment: your snippets are giving `Uncaught SyntaxError`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This because of `options` props take a time to arrives in `SearchableDropdown` component.

You need to use [`componentWillReceiveProps()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops)

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    console.log(props.options) //empty here
    this.state = {
      options: null, // options should be here
    }
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    if(nextProps.options !== this.props.options){
         this.setState({ options: nextProps.options })
    }
}

search = (event, { searchQuery }) => {
    console.log(searchQuery)
}

render () {
    console.log(this.props.options) //but filled here
    return (
        <Dropdown selection search onSearchChange={this.search} {...this.props}/>
    )
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `componentDidMount()` instead of `constructor()`. Maybe the problem is because when the `constructor()` is called,the parent component wasn't even mounted, so the props have not been passed yet.

Try it:

```
class SearchableDropdown extends Component {
   constructor(props){
      super(props)
   }
   componentDidMount(){
      console.log(this.props.options)
   }
   // ... rest of the code
}
```